# How big is $ H^{\frac{1}{2}}_{per} (0,2\pi) $?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Define $2\pi-$ periodic Sobolev function space as 
\begin{equation*}
 H^{r}_{per} (0,2\pi): = \{ \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} a_k e^{ikt}: \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} (1+k^2)^r\vert a_k \vert^2 < \infty  \} 
\end{equation*}
Let $ r =\frac{1}{2} $, how big is $ H^{\frac{1}{2}}_{per} (0,2\pi)$?

To ask more specifically,

1. Is it equivalent to $ H^{\frac{1}{2}} (0,2\pi) $, the classical Sobolev space of $ \frac{1}{2} $order?
2. Are wavelet (for instance, Haar function), finite element, spline, orthogonal polynomial (for instance,
   Legendre polynomial) contained in  $ H^{\frac{1}{2}}_{per}
   (0,2\pi)$?

Thank you in advance for your consideration in this question!

Comment: how is the classical sobolev space of $\frac{1}{2}$ order defined? I thought it was $H^{1/2}_{per}(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @mathworker21 You can refer to  (http://www.instmath.rwth-aachen.de/~heiko/lehre/varisemWS11-12/hitchikers_guide_fractional_sobolev_4_2011.pdf) for the definition of classical fractional Sobolev space.